# Data bus width and word size

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture

Will data bus width size change when word size changes?

I think that it will change because data bus width is usually in multiples of word size. So if word size changes, data bus width also changes.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you made a variant of x86 with 9-bit bytes / 36-bit "dword", then its internal and external busses would be multiples of that instead of multiples of 64 bits.

But otherwise no, **the ratios between word size and internal / external bus widths are flexible**.  You can let that ratio change as you widen various buses or increase the "word size" (or register width for non-integer registers).

---

[x86 since P5 Pentium is architecturally required have atomic 64-bit 
loads/stores for aligned pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)  By far the easiest way to implement this is with 64-bit / 128-bit / 256-bit / 512-bit data busses.  Intel was able to make that atomicity guarantee basically for free in P5 because they widened its external and internal data busses to 64-bit.  So even for "32-bit" x86 CPUs of that generation, 32-bit busses weren't an option if they wanted to be compatible with Pentium.

Modern x86 CPUs have internal data paths up to 512 bits (64-bytes) wide.  e.g. Skylake has a 64-byte wide path between L2 and L1 cache.  Skylake-AVX512 has 64-byte load/store units.  i.e. it can load/store whole cache lines at once.  (The external data bus is 64-bit DDR3/4 DRAM that does burst transfers of whole 64-byte cache lines.  Of course, for non-DRAM access, transfers go over PCIe)

---

Sandybridge / Ivybridge do AVX 256-bit loads/stores as two 128-bit (16-byte) halves, because the data path from execution units to L1D are only half as wide as the register size.    See [How can cache be that fast?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329789/how-can-cache-be-that-fast/329955#329955)

AMD Bulldozer-family and Ryzen split all 256-bit ops into 128-bit halves, so it's really two separate loads into two separate vector registers which get treated as one architectural YMM register.  This is different from SnB/IvB where `vaddps ymm` is a single uop, it's just that loads/stores need two cycles in the load/store execution unit because the bus isn't as wide as the physical registers.

With different FPU and SIMD register widths, the integer register width and "word size" are not as meaningful as they used to be!  The same concepts apply, but it's just register width not "word size" that matters.

Comment: Suppose P5 Pentium has 32 bit word size and 2 words data bus size. Now if I increase only the word size to 64 bit, is it necessary to increase the data bus to 128 bit or 4 words ?

Comment: @Zephyr: No, the ratio is flexible.  You could built a 64-bit x86 CPU with only 64-bit internal/external data paths, and in fact that's what AMD did with K8.  (It has to split 128-bit vector load/store into two 64-bit halves, just like Pentium III / Pentium-M which are 32-bit only but support 128-bit SSE registers).  The actual x86-64 ISA still doesn't guarantee atomicity for anything wider than 64 bits.

Comment: And of course if you were inventing your architecture and not aiming for full compat with P5, you could build an x86 with 64-bit integer registers but only a 32-bit external data bus (and only 32-bit internal data paths between caches).  IDK why you would; memory would become a huge bottleneck unless you clock those 32-bit busses very fast.  (Although wider data paths only for the L1 caches could make it fast when things fit in cache).   Anyway, nothing fundamental is stopping you, only really the atomicity guarantees you want to give.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  The 8086/8088 both had a word size of 16-bits.  The 8086 had a data bus of 16-bits, but the 8088 was only 8-bits.  80186/80188 and 80386/80386SX were similar.

Comment: So data bus width size is always fixed for a particular processor? Only the word size can change right?

Comment: @Zephyr: *everything* is fixed for a *particular* microarchitecture, e.g. all 80386SX chips are the same.